# Choosing query analyzer at query time in Solr

Tags: solr

I am indexing documents that have a large, textual content field. Most of the time I want to do special processing on that data, as well as on the incoming queries. (My current fieldType definition is at the bottom.)

However, sometimes, like when the user passes in something in quotation marks, I'd like to essentially use a different query analyzer than the one defined for the field. Maybe use a KeywordTokenizerFactory instead of a WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, so that I can match "multiple words in a phrase" without them being split apart.

How can I choose a different query analyzer at query time?

I understand that I can use copyField and setup an entirely different field definition, but this would essentially double the space used for my Solr index, which isn't feasible.

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting_reversed" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!-- convert things like é to e and ŕ to r -->
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnNumerics="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="word-delim-types.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
       maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
 </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <!-- convert things like é to e and ŕ to r -->
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"  types="word-delim-types.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: you have to have a different field and switch the request handler using the qt param for different analysis depending on the query from the user. Also, mark the fields as stored false so that the storage is not a big overhead for you and the terms would be shared across the index.

Comment: @Jayendra Thanks, I will experiment with this. I'm still worried about space use, since on my current field I already have stored=false, and the index is at 4GB. As an aside, since this other index would be used primarily for quoted phrases, and would therefore be used more often when the user wants to do some more precise matching, do you have any recommendations for the field definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible to dynamically change the analyzer used, but it requires some custom code. Check out [slide 30](https://www.slideshare.net/TomWinzig/clipboards/solr-dynamic-query-analyzer) in http://www.slideshare.net/treygrainger/semantic-multilingual-strategies-in-lucenesolr, where Trey is talking about using this approach to support different analyzers for multi-lingual fields. His approach has to do this for both indexing and query analysis, whereas for you it's just the query.

[Here's the JIRA feature request that Trey is referencing.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6492)

Comment: Thanks, I edited your answer to link directly to the documents in question.